# Обжалованы — в суд или в суде?

Tags: грамматика, управление, выбор-варианта

На сайте http://duma.gov.ru/news/48953/

> Статья 46
> 2. Решения и действия (или бездействие) органов государственной власти, органов местного самоуправления, общественных объединений и
> должностных лиц могут быть обжалованы **в суд**.

Вопросы:

- по какому принципу/правилу выбран именительный падеж слова "суд"?
- каким членом предложения является словосочетание "в суд"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> каким членом предложения является словосочетание "в суд".

*обжалованы (куда?) в суд* ⇒ обстоятельством места

> по какому принципу/правилу выбран именительный падеж слова "суд"

Не именительный, а *винительный*. Обстоятельство места со значением направления обычно выражаются винительным падежом: *идти в лес*, *наступать в лужу* и т.п.

Почему не использован вариант в предложном падеже «обжалованы (где?) в *суде*» — покрыто пеленой истории. В НКРЯ в основном корпусе «*в суд*» встречается немного чаще ([33](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexgramm&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&gramm1=&sem1=&flags1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%22%D0%B2%22&gramm2=&sem2=&flags2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&parent3=0&level3=0&min3=1&max3=1&lex3=%22%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%22&gramm3=&sem3=&flags3=&sem-mod3=sem&sem-mod3=sem2) против [21](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexgramm&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&gramm1=&sem1=&flags1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%22%D0%B2%22&gramm2=&sem2=&flags2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&parent3=0&level3=0&min3=1&max3=1&lex3=%22%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%22&gramm3=&sem3=&flags3=&sem-mod3=sem&sem-mod3=sem2)), но в газетном у «*в суде*» уже подавляющие преобладание ([13](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&level1=0&level2=0&level3=0&lex1=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&lex2=%22%D0%B2%22&lex3=%22%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%22&max2=1&max3=1&min2=1&min3=1&mode=paper&nodia=1&parent1=0&parent2=0&parent3=0&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod3=sem&sort=i_grtagging&text=lexgramm) против [256](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&level1=0&level2=0&level3=0&lex1=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&lex2=%22%D0%B2%22&lex3=%22%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%22&max2=1&max3=1&min2=1&min3=1&mode=paper&nodia=1&parent1=0&parent2=0&parent3=0&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod3=sem&sort=i_grtagging&text=lexgramm)). Т.е. «в суд» — это, скорее, юридический жаргон, а «в суде» — газетный штамп. В разговорной речи ИМХО второй вариант встречается куда чаще.

А если делать предположение о конкретном случае, то я бы сказал, что ничего особенного здесь нет: это просто личная языковая привычка тех, кто составлял сей документ.